# Python idiom for creating dict of dict of list

Tags: python

Given this data:

```
foo kk type1 1 2 3
bar kk type2 3 5 1
```

I would like to create a dictionary of dictionary of list.

In Perl it's called hash of hash of array.
It can be achieve with the following line (executable here https://eval.in/118535)

```
push @{$hohoa{$name}{$type}},($v1,$v2,$v3);
```

Output of $hohoa in Perl:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'bar' => {
                     'type2' => [
                                  '3',
                                  '5',
                                  '1'
                                ]
                   },
          'foo' => {
                     'type1' => [
                                  '1',
                                  '2',
                                  '3'
                                ]
                   }
        };
```

What's the way to do it in Python?

**Update:** Why the following `for loop` variation didn't store all the values?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import pprint
from collections import defaultdict

outerdict = defaultdict(dict)
with open('data.txt') as infh:
    for line in infh:
        name, _, type_, values = line.split(None, 3)

        valist = values.split();
        for i in range(len(valist)):
            thval = valist[i];
            outerdict[name][type] = thval

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
pp.pprint(outerdict)
```

It prints this:

```
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'foo': {<type 'type'>: '3'}, 'bar': {<type 'type'>: '1'}})
```

**Update 2:** The output seems problematic
when the data looks like this:

```
foo kk type1 1.2 2.10 3.3
bar kk type2 3.2 5.2 1.0
```

Comment: What's the expected result for the given input in Python?

Comment: what's the string `kk` used for?

Comment: `kk` is dummy content, we need not to care.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Python2

Comment: `defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to achieve; how many keys should be added to the inner dict?

The simplest way is to just create new dict literals for the inner dict:

```
outerdict = {}
outerdict[name] = {type_: [v1, v2, v3]}
```

or you could use `dict.setdefault()` to materialize the inner dict as needed:

```
outerdict.setdefault(name, {})[type_] = [v1, v2, v3]
```

or you could use [`collections.defaultdict()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to have it handle new values for you:

```
from collections import defaultdict

outerdict = defaultdict(dict)
outerdict[name][type_] = [v1, v2, v3]
```

When parsing a file line by line, I'd use the latter, albeit a little simplified:

```
from collections import defaultdict

outerdict = defaultdict(dict)
with open(filename) as infh:
    for line in infh:
        name, _, type_, *values = line.split()
        outerdict[name][type_] = [int(i) for i in values]
```

This uses Python 3 syntax to capture the remaining whitespace-delimited values on the line past the first 3 into `values`.

The Python 2 version would be:

```
with open(filename) as infh:
    for line in infh:
        name, _, type_, values = line.split(None, 3)
        outerdict[name][type_] = map(int, values.split())
```

where I limited the whitespace split to just 3 splits (giving you 4 values), then splitting the `values` string separately.

To have the inner-most list accumulate *all* values for repeated `(name, type_)` key combinations, you'll need to use a slightly more complex `defaultdict` setup; one that produces an *inner* `defaultdict()` set to produce `list` values:

```
outerdict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
with open(filename) as infh:
    for line in infh:
        name, _, type_, values = line.split(None, 3)
        outerdict[name][type_].extend(map(int, values.split()))
```

For the file you actually posted, I'd use a *different approach altogether*:

```
import csv
from itertools import islice

outerdict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

with open('ImmgenCons_all_celltypes_MicroarrayExp.csv', 'rb') as infh:
    reader = csv.reader(infh, skipinitialspace=True)
    # first row contains metadata we need
    celltypes = next(reader, [])[3:]

    # next two rows can be skipped
    next(islice(infh, 2, 2), None)

    for row in reader:
        name = row[1]
        for celltype, value in zip(celltypes, row[3:]):
            outerdict[name][celltype].append(float(value))
```

Comment: The number of inner dict `Type1` etc can be more than one.

Comment: @pdubois: then state that in your question. Are you parsing a file line by line?

Comment: If both of the dictionary keys might be repeated (and you want to concatenate the lists), you could further extend the `defaultdict` case by using `outerdict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))` and doing `outerdict[name][type].extend([v1, v2, v3])` for each line in your data.

Comment: @Blckknght: the Perl code will just overwrite the lists, I think.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes parsing line by line.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Let say instead of `values.split()` I'd like to append them through a for loop. How can I do that? See my update:

Comment: @pdubois: because you *replace* each previous value with a new. If you want to grow the lists under `[name][type_]` use the additional code I posted.

Comment: @pdubois: and apologies, I accidentally used `type` (a built-in function) vs. `type_` in places.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Hold on. The code seems to have problem when the data comes with integer value. see update again.

Comment: @pdubois: you never specified that the output should be converted to integers. :-) Added mapping to `int` for you.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I trid this http://dpaste.com/1718561/
With the following error: `   outerdict[name][type_].extend(map(int,thval))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '.'`

Comment: @pdubois: Sounds like you have floating point values instead of integers. **Be accurate in your question samples please**. Use `float` instead of `int`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I tried with `float` it gave me same error `ValueError: invalid literal for float(): .`

Comment: @pdubois because a single `.` is not a valid number... `.` by itself is used in some languages to indicate a missing value, so you either need to decide if it shouldn't be included, or if it's supposed to be equal to 0 or some other value..

Comment: @pdubois: right, so you have lines with `4 . .` or `. 54 20`, etc? What should be inserted for such strings? Can you include a sample of the *real* data you have?

Comment: @pdubois: see, that is a CSV file; using the `csv` module would have been more efficient to read that data. You also have floating point numbers in it, **not** single `.` characters. How did you split the lines if not on whitespace?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: This is the exact code to parse that data
http://dpaste.com/1718616/

Comment: @pdubois: I am out of time for now; will come back to this later. Please do use accurate data next time, your question has changed dramatically over the course of this conversation.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Your code almost there. My aim is  `name` takes gene symbol (e.g. Gm10568), `type` takes cell type (e.g. StemCells) and the values is the float value. 
So we should not skip first line where the cell type resides. We will use it later.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The desired output is `{'Gm10568': '{'StemCells':['16,1825','260.819',...,'16.1825`...]}`

Comment: @pdubois: you mean `[16.1825, 260.819, ..., 16.1825]`, right? Floating point values, not strings.

Comment: @pdubois: adjusted the code. You were looping over each individual column value, a string with `'16.1825'`, so you end up with integers from individual characters and an exception for the `.` in the string. No need to use `map()` here at all, just turn the whole column value into a float.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks. Was that a typo in line with `zip` ?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Did I miss anything? Check this: http://dpaste.com/1718854/ with error message.

Comment: @pdubois: no, I did; colon at the end of the line is missing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks a million for your patience in guiding me. I sincerely appreciate that. It works fine now.

Answer (score 3):

Another excellent way is to do the following:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

# eg.
d["x"]["y"].append(100)
```

In this way you are creating one dictionary of many dictionaries with default value of list.

Answer (score 1):

```
def make_strukture(lst_of_str):
    result = {}
    for i in my_strs:
        data = i.split()
        if data[0] in result.keys(): continue #Only one first key for foo, bar
        result[data[0]] = {} #Create first key foo, bar-level
        result[data[0]][data[2]] = list(data[3:]) #Skip kk and create second key with list
    return result

#Below more comples data structure:
my_strs = ["foo kk type1 1 2 3", "foo kk type2 1 2 3", "bar kk type2 3 5 1"]
print make_strukture(my_strs)
```

Print result:

```
{'foo':
    {'type1': ['1', '2', '3']},
 'bar': 
    {'type2': ['3', '5', '1']}
}
```

Comment: @MichaelKazarian: your output is wrong. `Foo` with `type2` should not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `defaultdict`, you can use a normal `dict` with `reduce` and `dict.setdefault`. Here's an example that could be wrapped into a function:

```
text_data = """foo kk type1 1 2 3
bar kk type2 3 5 1"""

data = [line.split() for line in text_data.splitlines()]
# [['foo', 'kk', 'type1', '1', '2', '3'], ['bar', 'kk', 'type2', '3', '5', '1']]

var1 = {}
for row in data:
    # row[:2] everything before leaf, [2] is the leaf, row[3:] remainder of 'values'
    reduce(lambda a,b: a.setdefault(b, {}), row[:2], var1)[2] = row[3:]
# {'foo': {'kk': {2: ['1', '2', '3']}}, 'bar': {'kk': {2: ['3', '5', '1']}}}
```

Then, wrap it up into a function with an optional converter for the values, eg:

```
def nested_dict(sequences, n, converter=lambda L: L):
    ret = {}
    for seq in sequences:
        reduce(lambda a,b: a.setdefault(b, {}), seq[:n-1], ret)[n] = map(converter, seq[n:])
    return ret

nested_dict(data, 2)
#{'foo': {2: ['type1', '1', '2', '3']}, 'bar': {2: ['type2', '3', '5', '1']}}
nested_dict(data, 3)
# {'foo': {'kk': {3: ['1', '2', '3']}}, 'bar': {'kk': {3: ['3', '5', '1']}}}
nested_dict(data, 3, int)
# {'foo': {'kk': {3: [1, 2, 3]}}, 'bar': {'kk': {3: [3, 5, 1]}}}
# ...
```

Comment: This is why we can't have nice things. Reading everything into memory and using `reduce()` to.. reduce readability? :-)

Comment: @Martijn `text_data` is from the example given at *I have this data*... the OP is having issues with nested dicts, it's not an untoward assumption that they're able to read a line from a file at a time (the data could be rows from a database table and the provide example was a just a simplified representation) :) `reduce` may be overkill for a couple of nesting levels, but scales better to multiple nesting levels and doesn't have the side-effect of requiring a `defaultdict` which may inadvertently create empty nodes for failed lookups instead of exceptions...

Comment: I was not entirely serious. I've used `reduce()` in answers in the past to handle arbitrary-depth dictionary nesting. Not the case here though, the Perl code certainly uses a fixed depth of keys.

Comment: @Martijn Indeed. This also handles fixed depth keys - it just so happens if they suddenly don't become fixed depth, it's far less hassle to have to cater for by amending a slice index, rather than a split and adding/removing variable names for the unpacking. (And yes, *I* know you're not entirely serious, but others may have viewed the comment differently, hence my reply :))